# Control gpio raspberry pi with Xbox360 controller

Tags: raspbian

My aim is to control the gpio of my rpi3a+ with the xbox360 controller and the Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receiver for Windows.

After installing xboxdrv I checked whether the wireless reveiver was detected with the command: lsusb. This gave:

"Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:02aa Microsoft Corp.

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub"

The xbox controller seemed to be connected with the receiver, since the top left section of the leds of the controller turned on. To test if the controller was detected I used the command:

sudo xboxdrv --detach-kernel-driver

Which resulted in:

`"xboxdrv 0.8.8 - http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/
Copyright © 2008-2011 Ingo Ruhnke 
Licensed under GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details.

-- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------
No Xbox or Xbox360 controller found"`

I also tried to connect manually by using --device-by-id VENDOR:PRODUCT and ----type TYPE, as proposed in this link: https://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/xboxdrv.html

This also turned out to be ineffective.

I hope that someone has more ideas on how to solve this problem.

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dmesg
[  330.704094] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[  330.914023] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[  330.914250] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[  331.156872] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02aa, bcdDevice= 3.30
[  331.156887] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  331.176892] input: Generic X-Box pad as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input1`

When I check for devices with ls `/dev/input` I get the following:

`by-id by-path event0 js0 mice`.

When I turn the controller of and search again with `ls /dev/input` I get:

`mice`.

So something of a connection is made.

Comment: I see you also need `sudo modprobe uinput` , have you follow the [git steps](https://github.com/xboxdrv/xboxdrv) ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I used the steps of https://github.com/FRC4564/Xbox.

Comment: "sudo modprobe uinput" did not give different results

Comment: ok, what is your `dmesg` output for the specific device ?

Comment: When I check for devices with ls /dev/input I get the following:   by-id  by-path  event0  js0  mice.  When I turn the controller of and search again with ls /dev/input I get: mice. So something of a connection is made.

Comment: Please don't use comments for additional ouput. It is unreadable. Instead edit your question and put it into it.